# How can I remove a column from this equation?

Tags: google-sheets

```
=iferror(sort(filter($C$6:$G$60,$H$6:$H$60='Guild Stats'!V3),4,false),"")
```

I want to remove column D from this equation so that when it pulls from the db sheet it will display the results from there.

Answer (score 1):

Replace:

`... filter($C$6:$G$60,...`

with

`... filter({$C$6:$C$60,$E$6:$G$60},...`

More info here:
https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6208276?hl=en

Comment: It took a bit of work, but I figured it out finally, Thanks so much for your help.
end result: =iferror(sort(filter({$C$6:$C$60,$E$6:$G$60},$H$6:$H$60='Guild Stats'!V3),4,false),"")